# From Unity to Hololens Emulator, gameobject disappeared

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens-emulator

Unity 2021.1.6 with MRTK-1.0.2104.3, Windows SDK 10.0.19041.1144 with Hololens Emulator,

I dropped a cube at  (0,0, 0.5), a button at (0, -0.1, 0.17). Unity Game Mode works fine with the gameOjct and the CPU panel.

[image]
[image]

Build with HoloLens x64 and other settings as show. Then I open the sln with Visual Studio 2019. Debug with x64 Hololens 2 Emulator. The emulator starts with no error, I can open/close Hololens main menu with "Windows" button on my keyboard. After that, just black screen without my GameObject. Any hint what the problem might be?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check your MixedRealityToolkit gameobject. There seems to be some misconfigured input profiles. Close Unity Project and delete the Library Folder. Reopen your project and let it load. Check if you get errors when opening your scene, and fix them. Probably a misconfigured MRTK Profile is the reason (as seen in the picture)